# How to make the pop-up calendar in Bootstrap-DatePicker works like button?

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

[image: datepicker]

Hi..

As you see in the picture above, there is a popup datepicker and a blue button named **Filter**.

Currently, I must click **Filter** button to run this filter form. Do you have any idea about how to run this form directly after I click/choose the year so I could remove the **Filter** button?

I have tried this, but it did not work,

```
$('.date-own').datepicker({
         minViewMode: 2,
         format: 'yyyy',
                 autoclose: true
       })
             .on(changeYear, function() {
             window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
         });
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Make the datepicker as a form, wirte a JS function that triggers onChange of the input. It chenged, auto submit the form with the `submit()` method of JS. Or simply use the callback function provided by the datepicker and redirect directly in there ;)

Comment: Have you checked the docs for bootstrap datetime events, the update event to be specific?https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpupdate

Comment: @Cemal it's not the same library I think he's using this one http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Comment: @William-H-M I stand corrected. http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changeyear is the right url for this then

Comment: @Cemal I jusr read it, now I am trying to find out how to use it. Could you help me? please.. I am new in programming

Comment: @William-H-M I have update the question above with the script for the datepicker. But it does not work.. could you help me?

Comment: @Cemal I have update the question above with the script for the datepicker. But it does not work.. could you help me?

Comment: @AndriSetiawan if any of the answers satisfy your needs, choose one of them as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate

> The event handler will be passed an object with the properties below

- **date**: the relevant Date object, in local timezone. For a multidate picker, this will be the latest date picked.
- **dates**: an Array of Date objects, in local timezone, when using a multidate picker.
- **format([ix], [format])**: a function to make formatting date easier. ix can be the index of a Date in the dates array to format; if absent, the last date selected will be used. format can be any format string that datepicker supports; if absent, the format set on the datepicker will be used. Both arguments are optional.

So according to that, your code should be as below. Please notice that the event name on the binding is wrapped in double quotes.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('.date-own').datepicker({
     minViewMode: 2,
     format: 'yyyy',
     autoclose: true
   }).on("changeYear", function(e) {
      window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/somePage.php?d="+e.date.getFullYear());
   });
});
```

Comment: Cool! this code is running as what I want :) Thanks

Comment: Glad that it's. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Waht you should do is listen to the [`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event, that is fired when you select a date (It doesn't matter if is a year) this event should be the one using as if in case your requirement changed to be year and month then [`changeYear`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changeyear) event wouldn't work.

> Fired when the *view* year is changed from decade view.

```js
$('.date-own').datepicker({
    minViewMode: 2,
    format: 'yyyy',
    autoclose: true
  })
  .on("changeDate", function(e) {
    let year = e.date.getFullYear();
    //window.location.replace("http://localhost/analytics/tables.php?year=" + year);
    console.log('window.location.replace("http://localhost/analytics/tables.php?year=' + year);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group date date-own" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yours look definitely better than mine, however he's asking for the change in years, so *changeDate* should be *changeYear*

Comment: This is not the case because, as per the documentation, `changeYear` is when the view has been changed (example from decades to years, then the event will fire), so if instead of year now have year and month `changeYear` will be useless

Comment: I agree with you on what the documentation says (undoubtedly of course), however the `changeYear` event only fires when a year is clicked, contrary to what document says. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cemalg/z1r781o7/1/)

Comment: Yeah, it does but now change your parameter of format to be `YYYY-MM`, you need the date (requirement changes that our _loved_ clients do...) and you will see that now It won't work, `changeDate` is more general and all use case

Comment: well, it's probably not working due to `YYYY` being an unknown identifier to datepicker. it should have been `yyyy-MM`, then it will work. I agree with our *beloved clients' requirements* though. :)

Comment: Ohh right, I thought It'll will work the same as with moment and eonasdan, but yeah change it to yyyy, and It'll will show what I said, in conjugation with `minViewMode: 1`

Comment: well , to be honest didn't try with `minViewMode: 1` as the OP already set it as`minViewMode: 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163516/discussion-between-william-h-m-and-cemal).